# PHP PSR-0 + several namespaces in one file and autoload

Tags: php

I've been thinking for a while about defining several namespaces in one php file and so, having several classes inside this file.

Suppose, I want to implement something like `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr`:

```
Expr.php
Expr
|-- Andx.php
|-- Base.php
|-- Comparison.php
|-- Composite.php
|-- From.php
|-- Func.php
|-- GroupBy.php
|-- Join.php
|-- Literal.php
|-- Math.php
|-- OrderBy.php
|-- Orx.php
`-- Select.php
```

It would be nice if I had all of this in one file - `Expr.php`:

```
namespace Doctrine\ORM\Query;
class Expr {
    // code
}

namespace Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr;

class Func {
    // code
}

// etc...
```

What I'm thinking of is directories naming convention and, unlike [`PSR-0`](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) having several classes and namespaces in one file. It's best explained by the code:

```
ls Doctrine/orm/query
Expr.php
```

that's it - only `Expr.php`

Since `Expr.php` is somewhat I call a "meta-namespace" for `Expr\Func`, it make sense to place all the classes inside Expr.php (as shown above).

So, the vendor name is still starts with an uppercased letter (`Doctrine`) and the other parts of namespace start with lowercased letter. We can write an autoload so it would respect this notion:

```
function load_class($class) {
    if (class_exists($class)) {
        return true;
    }
    $tokenized_path = explode(array("_", "\\"), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
    // array('Doctrine', 'orm', 'query', 'Expr', 'Func');
    //                                    ^^^^
    // first, we are looking for first uppercased namespace part
    // and if it's not last (not the class name), we use it as a filename 
    // and wiping away the rest to compose a path to a file we need to include
    if (FALSE !== ($meta_class_index = find_meta_class($tokenized_path))) {
        $new_tokenized_path = array_slice($tokenized_path, 0, $meta_class_index);
        $path_to_class = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $new_tokenized_path);
    }
    else { // no meta class found
        $path_to_class = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $tokenized_path);
    }
    if (file_exists($path_to_class.'.php')) {
        require_once $path_to_class.'.php';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Another reason to do so is to reduce a number of php files scattered among directories.
Usually you check file existence before you require a file to fail gracefully:

```
file_exists($path_to_class.'.php');
```

If you take a look at actual [`Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php) code, you'll see they use all of the "inner-classes", so you actually do:

```
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/AndX.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Base.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Comparison.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Composite.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/From.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Func.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/GroupBy.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Join.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Literal.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Math.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/OrderBy.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Orx.php");
file_exists("/path/to/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Select.php");
```

in your autoload which causes quite a few I/O reads.
Isn't it too much to check on each user's hit?

I'm just putting this on a discussion.

I want to hear from another PHP programmers what do they think of it.
And, of course, if you have a silver bullet addressing this problems I've designated here, please share.

I also have been thinking if my vogue question fits here and according to [`the FAQ`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) it seems like this question addresses "software architecture" problem *slash* proposal.

I'm sorry if my scribble may seem a bit clunky :)
Thanks.

Comment: another solutions: `class_map.php` inside a directory with a namespace? `phar`? caching paths of loaded classes in `apc cache`?

Comment: Have you thought of just putting everything in a phar archive? Still a file per class (easier to maintain), but a bit less strain on the filesystem (especially with APC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep using a single file per class.

You use APC, right? If you don't, start doing it right now. APC will cache the opcode, thus there will be no performance hit on the file checking.

It's not worth losing so much readability.

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced, that you really want to have all your classes in one file. Of course it is possible, but I wouldn't want to maintain it. You can use [multiple namespaces in one file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php). There are two allowed syntaxes:

**Example #1 Declaring multiple namespaces, simple combination syntax**

```
<?php
namespace MyProject;

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }

namespace AnotherProject;

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }
?>
```

**Example #2 Declaring multiple namespaces, bracketed syntax**

```
<?php
namespace MyProject {

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }
}

namespace AnotherProject {

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }
}
?>
```

I would go with the second one, for readability, maintenance and error avoidance reasons.

***However, I don't like the idea of using one file for multiple classes***. I would suggest to use one file per class, organized in folders according to your namespace. This allows you to use really straightforward autoloading:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $className = (string) str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    if(file_exists($className)) {
        include_once($className . '.class.php');
    } else {
        // throw class not found
    }
});
```

Thats a pattern I usually use in my applications. If you are concerned about IO and speed, I would look at the things Yannis Rizos mentioned:

> Have you thought of just putting everything in a phar archive? Still a
>   file per class (easier to maintain), but a bit less strain on the
>   filesystem (especially with APC).

You could even use the [HipHop compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tested phar archive - it still performs IO operations to get a certain class from an archive (so, it seems like the archive itself does not remain in the memory! `APC` in this case probably would be a saver, but I hardly can say it's maintainable). `HipHop` is an overkill + introducing hiphop in our project will bring a lot of problems.

Comment: `I would suggest to use one file per class, organized in folders according to your namespace` - this is what I do now and this is exactly why I've posted this topic. I actually solved the problem, - what I did is: I wrote a script that I run before deploying that compiles all the classes into a single php file and makes a file for class autoloader which contains information about which classes the generated file contain. It works fine for several weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

You were asking if the classes in question would cause IO on every class. But you might overlooked this code at the beginning of the autoload function

```
if (class_exists($class)) {
    return true;
}
```

as soon as the 'container' file Expr.php is loaded, all the classes inside will be registered in php and therefore every subsequent call to autoload would result in `class_exists() == true`

If you decide to have several classes in one file, simply make sure that the class which would resolve the autoload correctly is used before any other inline classes. This would effectively save I/O compared to the one-class-per-file approach.